# Force QuickTime Player to auto-play files

Tags: mac, quicktime

I want QuickTime Player to auto-play a file when I execute that file from Finder.

The default behaviour is to simply load the file and wait for you to press play.

I found a default pref that you can set to force [QuickTime X to play movie files automatically](http://techpatio.com/2009/software/os/how-to-quicktime-x-autoplay-movies-open-snow-leopard).

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 1
```

How can you force QuickTime to play all its files automatically, regardless of their type (mp3, wav, aac, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Just use Quick Look instead.  Click on the video file to select it.  Then tap your space-bar, and the video will appear in Quick Look.  Watch it however you wish to.  Then when you're finished, just tap your space-bar again and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Using the default will command QuickTime to start playback of the loaded file.

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 1
```

It's not file specific, or movie specific. It will play all files, regardless of type if you run this command, and restart QuickTime.

Comment: This will not work for QuickTime Player on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Doesn't work in High Sierra either, sadly.